# Parallel Bezier Curves in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use Bezier curves to draw a track in Ti*k*Z, e.g., a racetrack.

I have the centerline of the track specified with the help of Bezier curves, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[dashed,blue] (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I now want to draw the boundary of the track which is always a distance d from the centerline.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome! You have some code which you now want to adapt. You don't know how to do it. However, you think that we, who do not have any idea what your code contains, will be able to tell you. Do you see the problem? Please edit your question to include code for a minimal document which shows the problem and which we can copy-paste-compile to produce the  centreline. However, your best bet is to add `double, double distance=<width between lines>, line width=<width of each line>` etc. to the existing path.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit lazy. Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: Thanks for editing. Could you post your answer as an answer? It doesn't make sense to have it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @cfr pointed out, this is easily achievable with the *double distance* key. Hence, the following code achieves what I want:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

   \draw[solid,red,double distance=10pt] (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);
   \draw[dashed,blue] (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr: Any idea how to get rid of these small gray lines at the start and end of the border?